# Expected value of nonlinear combination of random variables with known expected value

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Suppose that the random variable $x$ has expected value $0$ and known finite moments $m_{xi}$ and that it can take any real value, and that the random variable $y$ has expected value $1$ and known finite moments $m_{yi}$ and that it can take only positive real values ($0$ excluded). Is it possible to find the expected value of the following random variable $z$?

$$z=\sqrt{(x-1)^2-\frac{1}{y}}$$

Comment: 1. The distribution of z depends on the joint distribution of your original variables. 2. In any case, there seems to be no guarantee here that $(x-1)^2-\frac{1}{y}$ will be positive, which will present you with a problem. 3. Note further than having all moments finite (and knowing the entire moment sequence) is not necessarily sufficient to determine the distribution. As an example, the moment sequence of the lognormal distribution is not unique to the lognormal, but shared with still other distributions. ,,, ctd

Comment: 4. In some circumstances (with sufficient other information) it may be feasible to approximate the mean of a function of two random variables in therms of the moments of the inputs.